# Saving category_id for new post in django

Tags: python, django

I have a problem when saving/creating new post for blog.
I already have Post model and each post has it's own category. so I have Category model too. In CreateView template I already got all categories from DB and displayed in select/option tag. The issue is I want to save category_id when I create new post. But I don't know how? How can I say if form POSTED get category_id and save it for Post model that has category_id field?

### View:

```
class PostCreateForm(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'short_text', 'long_text', 'post_pic']

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostCreateForm, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['categories'] = Category.objects.all().order_by('id')
        return context


    def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

### Model:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Post(models.Model):
    title               = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    short_text          = models.TextField()
    long_text           = models.TextField()
    post_pic            = models.ImageField(default="post_pic.jpg", 
    blank=False, upload_to='post_pics')
    date_published      = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    date_upadated       = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    author              = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category            = models.ForeignKey(Category, default=None, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})`
```

### post_form.html

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block title_head %}
    New Post
{% endblock title_head %}
{% block content %}
     <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4 pb-2">New Post</legend>
               {{ form|crispy }}
        <select class="form-control" name="category">
            {% for category in categories %}
                <option value="{{ category.id }}">{{ category }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
        </fieldset>

        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info">Post</button>
        </div>

     </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: You've excluded the category field from the list of fields in the form for some reason. Why have you done that? And why have you output the category select separately?

Comment: Solved thanks. 
I didn't know that category field  is accessible from list of fields. 
I tried to fetch all categories from db and display them in select/option tag then set option's value equal to category_id and get category id after submit form and then save in category field for post.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to achieve this. Here is the simplest:

If you expect the Catagories to remain the same then you can hard code them and use a `CharField` with the [`choices=`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices) keyword on your `Post` model.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        ('Horror', 'Horror'),
        ('Romance', 'Romance'),
        ('Comedy', 'Comedy'),
    )
    category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
```

Then all you need to do is add `'category'` to your fields list in the CreateView.

---

*Side Note* You should probs rename your `CreateView` it's a view not a form. This may cause confusion.

Comment: No actually I wanna select categories from database and I did it.
and about CreateView I think It's true and there is no problem in saving new post in db except when I submit form I get this error 
NOT NULL constraint failed: blog_post.category_id

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

we have access category in list of fields so it's useless to fetch all categories then displaying them in select-option tag in html page. just add category field in list of fields

Change PostCreateForm

### change it from this

```
class PostCreateForm(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'short_text', 'long_text', 'post_pic']

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostCreateForm, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['categories'] = Category.objects.all().order_by('id')
        return context


    def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

### to this

```
class PostCreateForm(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'short_text', 'long_text', 'post_pic', 'category']

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostCreateForm, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context


    def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```